# How to set STYLE which work only on down side controls?

Tags: html, css

I want to set style for `<td>` tag, I am designing table in a page. I want to give different styles for upper and lower cells, is that possible to set `<style>` which only do work on down side `<td>` tags.

Please Help.

Comment: what to you mean upper and lower cells, do you mean header and other cells or you mean alternate row similar styling

Comment: add your html code for better understanding.

Comment: No, Actually I have many rows in a table, On first 10 rows I don't want to give lines, but after that I want to give lines.

Comment: I would appreciate if [Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) created, to solve your problem easily!

Comment: apart from assign a class in every '<td>' tag, I can directly set style in every tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer...

Just set the particular rows in any tag like `<thead>, <tbody> or <tfoot>`

```
<table id="table1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

then set style

```
<style>
    table thead td
    {
        border:none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you either give a class to lower `<td>` tags and then inside `<style>` you can set their style. or you can use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) css selector without giving your `<td>` elements a class.

Here is a [representation](http://jsfiddle.net/4wqw0s8a/1/) of what I just said:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="lowertd">2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="lowertd">2</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
#table1 tr td:last-child {
    background-color: green;
}
.lowertd {
    background-color: silver;
}
#table1 tr td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you need to create a `css class` and reference it by

```
<td class="someclass" ........... >
```

although you want to add this class, only for elements for which you need styling.

and in CSS under `<style>` , define css attributes.  Something like below

```
<style>
.someclass{
property: value;
.
.
.
}
</style>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the first 10 `<td>` tags differently by using the nth-of-type selector and then setting a style for those elements:

`td:nth-child(-n+10) { text-decoration: underline; }`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q4c5e77/1/)